# from title to data-* by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, title

I have a div element

```
<div class="test2" title="space enter=fadeIn exit=fadeout,scaleOut dur=1.2" >blahblahblah</div>
```

After magic jQuery script I want that it will be like that

```
<div  class="test2" data-enter="fadeIn" data-exit="fadeOut scaleOut" data-duration="1.2" title="space enter=fadeIn exit=fadeout,scaleOut dur=1.2" > blahblahblah
</div>
```

So I tried to manipulate with this

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[title*='space']").each(function() {
       var title = $(this).attr('title');
       var titleArray = title.split(" ");
       $(this).attr("data-enter", titleArray[1]);
       $(this).attr("data-exit", titleArray[2]);
       $(this).attr("data-duration", titleArray[3]);
       $(this).removeAttr('title');
    });
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't work properly, cause I have data-exit="fadeOut scaleOut" with two properties and my script is for div like that

```
<div class="test2" title="space fadeIn fadeout 1.2" >blahblahblah</div>
```

But I don't want it.
Maybe you know right solution for this example. Maybe some find or replaceWith function will help for this.
Thanks. I hope you understood my question.

Comment: You have to further split those values `titleArray[1].split('=')[1]`. http://jsfiddle.net/whcjxh53/

Comment: Why should you want to have such data in the title attribute in the first place? It's visible to the user on mouseover and not semantically intended to conain any data.

Comment: @Connum Because it help me to manipulate page properties and after this script I do always removeAttr('title')

Comment: @ShaunakD Thanks it was helpful but If I replace values in title it will doesn't work for me properly.
And in title I want to change exit=fadeOut,scaleOut to data-exit="fadeOut scaleOut". But in real life it seems like data-exit="fadeOut,scaleOut" =((

Comment: I still don't get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is job for regular expressions. Something like this:

```js
$("[title*='space']").each(function() {

    var title = this.title,
        enter = this.title.match(/enter=(.*?)(\s|$)/),
        exit  = this.title.match(/exit=(.*?)(\s|$)/),
        duration = this.title.match(/dur=(.*?)(\s|$)/)
        
    $(this).attr("data-enter", enter[1]);
    $(this).attr("data-exit", exit[1].replace(/,/, ' '));
    $(this).attr("data-duration", duration[1]);
    $(this).removeAttr('title');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test2" title="space enter=fadeIn exit=fadeout,scaleOut dur=1.2" >blahblahblah</div>
```

Comment: It is fantastic work. 100 from 10 points. It is work perfect. Thank you. You are magic man.

Comment: Can you explain about this regular expressions and  how it works?
/dur=(.*?)(\s|$)/ - what does it mean? 
If dur=90 or -200 will it be work?
And if I will need 16 strings of data-* and will it work with that?