# why does empty attribute break script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, title, typeerror

It is my lovely title.
So I tried to manipulate with title for Scrollme.js. And here my script code which it got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828199/from-title-to-data-by-jquery).
I have some manipulate with that and:

```js
$("[title*='aniscroll']").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass("scrollme animateme");
  var title = this.title,
    when = this.title.match(/when=(.*?)(\s|$)/),
    from = this.title.match(/from=(.*?)(\s|$)/),
    ...
    crop = this.title.match(/crop=(.*?)(\s|$)/)

  $(this).attr("data-when", when[1]);
  $(this).attr("data-from", from[1]);
  ...
  $(this).attr("data-crop", crop[1]);
});
```

```html
<div class="test" title="aniscroll when=enter from=0.5 to=0 opacity=0 rotatex=90 translatex=-200">
```

It doesn't work for me properly, cause after that script I have

```html
<div class="test scrollme animateme" data-when="enter" data-from="0.5" data-to="0" data-opacity="0" data-translatex="-200" style="opacity: 0.77; transform: translate3d(-45px, 0px, 0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);"><!-- simple frame --></div>
```

And it animates only opacity and translatex but where my rotatex. And there is an error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

But if I will swap of $(this).attr("... to:

```js
//Манипуляции с data-attr

$("[title*='aniscroll']").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass("scrollme animateme");
  var title = this.title,
    when = this.title.match(/when=(.*?)(\s|$)/),
    from = this.title.match(/from=(.*?)(\s|$)/),
   ...
    crop = this.title.match(/crop=(.*?)(\s|$)/)

  $(this).attr("data-when", when[1]);
  $(this).attr("data-from", from[1]);
 ...
  $(this).attr("data-crop", crop[1]);
});
```

It will work perfectly for my this specific test title but if I will change title and add `"roatatez"` to it it doesn't work.

> So problem is in emplty attribute and I don't know how to fix it.

Maybe it will need to add some "if condition" to work properly. Maybe you know solution about this? Thanks for your future answers.

I hope you understood my question.

---

So I use your third script and get it

```js
$("[title*='aniscroll']").each(function() {
 
  var attrs = ["when", "from", "to", "opacity" "translatex", "translatey", "translatez", "rotatex", "rotatey", "rotatez", "scale", "scalex", "scaley", "scalez", "easing", "crop"];
  var title = this.title;
  var $this = $(this);
  attrs.forEach(function(attr) {
      var value = title.match(new RegExp(attr + "=(.*?)(\\s|$)"));
      if (value) {
        $this.attr("data-" + attr, value[1]);
      }
});
  
  
});
```

And I have mistalke:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
>   And nothing heppened with div

Comment: Is all this code really relevant to question?

Comment: Yes, of course. Because stackoverflow said me: "Be specific"

Comment: SO also "says" another important thing: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't read it. 
I am afraid that my questions will be not clear and my account will be blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to make it conditional depending on whether you got a match from any given test.

For instance, to make it work with `when`:

```
if (when) $(this).attr("data-when", when[1]);
```

...which won't add the `data-attr` at all if there wasn't a match, or

```
$(this).attr("data-when", when ? when[1] : "");
```

....which will add it with a blank value when there wasn't a match.

---

Side note: When you have massive blocks of repetitive code, that's a sign you want to refactor. :-) For instance, in this code, you can do something like this:

```
var attrs = ["when", "from", "to", "opacity"/*...*/];
var title = this.title;
var $this = $(this);
attrs.forEach(function(attr) {
    var value = title.match(new RegExp(attr + "=(.*?)(\\s|$)"));
    if (value) {
        $this.attr("data-" + attr, value[1]);
    }
});
```